# How to find a pattern, and replace it differently?

Tags: regex, linux

I'm having problems with removing duplicate lines in a file, and replacing them a with a non-duplicate line. Ideally, I would just like to replace it with a continuous sequence, so that the duplicate lines could be separated.

I was considering sed with some kind of wildcard (*):

```
sed -e "s/text_pattern/text_pattern*/g" my_file.txt
```

So that a new number is added to the text_pattern every time is returns. However, I haven't been able to find a proper solution in the man pages and on the internet. Does anybody have an idea of how to do something like this? Perhaps sed is not the best choice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Awk` seems more suitable for this task. I'm going to assume you don't really need a regex, but want to match the complete line with a fixed string. Then you can do this:

```
awk -v ln="text_pattern" '$0 == ln { $0 = $0 " " ++i };1' my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe sed is the tool for this. If you need regular expressions for tasks like these, you could go with perl (which builds upon both awk *and* sed).

```
cat test | perl -e '$i = 1; while (<>) { chomp($_); if (s/pattern/pattern$i/) { $i++ }; print $_."\n"; }'
```

That is, for each line in stdin: Remove newline, then append the counter to pattern, iff you find it. And, if you find it, increase it by 1. Then print the line.

EDIT: test is your input file.

Answer (score 0):

**uniq**

- `uniq -c input.txt` shows you the frequency of occurrences.
- `uniq -u input.txt` prints unique lines.

**awk**

- `awk 'x[$0]++' input.txt`   prints the duplicate lines.
- `awk '!x[$0]++' input.txt`  deletes duplicate lines.

**sed**

- `sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/P; D' input.txt`  prints the duplicate lines.
- `sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' input.txt`  deletes duplicate lines.